# failed to compile my vue app with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, laravel-mix, vuelidate

Previously it was working fine but after when i try npm run update is got this error whenever i try npm run watch. I am using vue js with typescript and laravel - mix .

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ illness: { required: ValidationRuleWithoutParams<any>; }; relationship: { required: ValidationRuleWithoutParams<any>; }; description: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidationArgs<{ illness: string; relationship: string; description: string; }> | Ref<ValidationArgs<{ illness: string; relationship: string; description: string; }>>'.
  Type '{ illness: { required: ValidationRuleWithoutParams<any>; }; relationship: { required: ValidationRuleWithoutParams<any>; }; description: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidationArgs<{ illness: string; relationship: string; description: string; }>'.
    Types of property 'illness' are incompatible.
      Type '{ required: ValidationRuleWithoutParams<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidationRule<string>'.
```

i tired to restore my package.json and deleted my node modules folder and re installed everything but still i get this error.

here is my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "app",
    "version": "4.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": [
        "Pharmacy",
        "pos",
        "software"
    ],
    "author": "Muhammad",
    "license": "ISC",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@chenfengyuan/vue-barcode": "^2.0.0",
        "@sideway/address": "^4.1.1",
        "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.25",
        "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.21",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "chart.js": "^3.2.2",
        "chokidar": "^3.5.1",
        "core-js": "^3.9.0",
        "joi": "^17.4.0",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.29",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
        "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
        "primevue": "^3.12.1",
        "prosemirror-utils": "^0.9.6",
        "quill": "^1.3.7",
        "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
        "v-tooltip": "^2.1.2",
        "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
        "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
        "vue-fullscreen": "^3.0.11",
        "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.4",
        "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
        "vuex": "^4.0.0",
        "webcam-easy": "^1.0.5",
        "webpack": "^5.69.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.2",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.0-beta.11",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.4",
        "resolve-typescript-plugin": "^1.1.5",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.7",
        "typescript": "^4.6.2",
        "vue": "^3.0.2",
        "vue-loader": "^16.0.0-beta.9"
    }
}
```

Here is the file where its pointing error

```
export default class FamilyHistory extends Vue {
    private recordList = [];
    private recordID = 0;
    private submitted = false;
    private pService;
    private illnessList = [];
    private relationshipList = [];
    private toast;
    private componentName = "";
    private vuexStore = useStore();

    private state = reactive({
        illness: "",
        relationship: "",
        description: "",
    });

    private validationRules = {
        illness: {
            required,
        },
        relationship: {
            required,
        },
        description: {
            required,
        },
    };

    private v$ = useVuelidate(this.validationRules, this.state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` is messed up.

In `dependencies` you have both the packages `@vuelidate/core`/`@vuelidate/validators` which is [Vuelidate for Vue 3](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/#installation) and `"vuelidate": "^0.7.6"` which is package [Vuelidate 0.x for Vue 2](https://vuelidate.js.org/)

Either you are somewhere importing the wrong type or just TS is loading type definitions from wrong package (due to duplication). Hard to tell without seeing all the code...

Just remove the package for Vue 2 as you are using Vue3

*and btw `vue` should be probably in your `dependencies`, not `devDependencies`*